# JavaScript function in an external file won't run

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
function phone() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/gi)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/gi)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/gi)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/gi)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/gi)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/gi)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/gi)
 ){
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel=stylesheet id="style" href='style.css'/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="phone.js"></script>
  <script>
   phone();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The external function won't run when the page opens why is that? I even tried doing onload but nothing happened. When the page opens it should print in the console either true or false but absolutely nothing is printed.

Comment: You aren't calling `console.log()` anywhere, so it won't print anything

Comment: `"but nothing happened"` - Why do you expect something to happen?  What line of code here would *cause* anything to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not actually printing the result. You need to change to this:

```
    <script>
        console.log( "Is phone: " + phone() );
    </script>
```